# Radio button style not working

Tags: html, css

Radio button style not working in mozilla. in IE it works

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="rate[]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" class="radio" >
```

**CSS**

```
.radio {
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    border: #FF0000 1px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The styling of radion buttons depends on the user OS .

please refer this site http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/styling-form-controls-revisited/radio-button/

Comment: so what? just because IE allows you to override things that shouldn't be overridden at all except by using a completely custom control it doesn't mean other browsers have to do stuff like that, too.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers render some controls using the built-in OS controls, and you have no control on them, their look and feel will change according the user's OS theme and Radio buttons are one of them.