# Radio Buttons Width

Tags: css, layout, jquery-mobile

I need to change the width of a grouped radio button but I can't do it.
I've tried to add `style=width:...px` but it doesn't work.

I am using jQuery Mobile and Cordova.

How can I fix it?

### HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-inline="true">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inline="true">
        <legend>Question1:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-1">OK</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-2">KO</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-3">N.A.</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio button style not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4573494/radio-button-style-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Try applying `width` styles to the `<label>` elements:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" data-inline="true">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-inline="true">
        <legend>Question1:</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-1" style="width: 100px;">OK</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-2" style="width: 100px;">KO</label>
        <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"/>
        <label for="radio-choice-3" style="width: 100px;">N.A.</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="basic" value=""/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ncYz/).

Note that if you want all the labels to have the same width, creating a CSS rule that assigns that width to a class then adding that class to your labels will reduce code duplication.

Comment: Ok! It seems working now! And what should I do to enlarge the legend ? I've tried to write
<legend style="width:100px;"> but it seems not working

Comment: @Riccardo, the `<legend>` element is replaced by a `<div>` that exposes the `ui-controlgroup-label` class. The CSS rule `.ui-controlgroup-label { width: <your width>; }` should work.